# Pipe python function's results

Tags: python, function, stdout, piping

I have functions that return some results. I would like to access those functions as libraries: they will be imported and used in some larger scripts. That is straightforward. However, I would like to use those functions as separate scripts which will output the results to `stdout` for piping purposes. Does it make sense to write my function this way?

```
def myfunction(params=(), to_stdout=False): 
  result = whatever_i_want_to_process(params)
  if to_stdout is True:
    sys.stdout.writelines(result)
  return result
```

Or are there better, more efficient, and more intuitive ways of doing what I want?

---

### EDIT 1

To be more specific, each function takes a raw input (either from `stdin` or a raw string), and adds something to it:

```
def add_name(content, to_stdout=False): 
    result = content + "\nadded name"
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result

def add_surname(content, to_stdout=False): 
    result = content + "\nadded surname"
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result

def add_name_and_surname(content, to_stdout=False):
    result = add_surname(add_name(content))
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result
```

So I would like to make use of the two first functions as libraries, nothing to change here, but I'd also like to be able ot call those two functions as shell scripts which results could be piped:

```
$ echo "Here is my content" | add_name
```

Is there an pygical approach to do it? Would testing the `to_stdout` variable make sense in the first place or is it error prone and inefficient?

I am also thinking about using the `click` library to easily build commands from functions.

---

### EDIT 2

Using the `click` library the functions would look like this:

```
import click
import os, sys

@click.command()
@click.argument('content', required=False)
@click.option('--to_stdout', default=True)
def add_name(content, to_stdout=False):
    if not content:
        content = ''.join(sys.stdin.readlines())
    result = content + "\n\tadded name"
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result


@click.command()
@click.argument('content', required=False)
@click.option('--to_stdout', default=True)
def add_surname(content, to_stdout=False):
    if not content:
        content = ''.join(sys.stdin.readlines())
    result = content + "\n\tadded surname"
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result

@click.command()
@click.argument('content', required=False)
@click.option('--to_stdout', default=False)
def add_name_and_surname(content, to_stdout=False):
    result = add_surname(add_name(content))
    if to_stdout is True:
        sys.stdout.writelines(result)
    return result
```

This way I am able to generate the three commands "add_name", "add_surname" and "add_name_and_surname" using a `setup.py` file and `pip install --editable .` Then I am able to pipe:

```
$ echo "original content" | add_name | add_surname 
original content

    added name
    added surname
```

However there is one slight problem I need to solve, when composing with different `click` commands as functions:

```
$echo "original content" | add_name_and_surname 
Usage: add_name_and_surname [OPTIONS] [CONTENT]

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (r i g i n a l   c o n t e n t 
)
```

I have no idea why I get that result.

Comment: Using a mutable default arg is a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham corrected that!

Comment: I edited my post. It's not about logging, its about using library functions as commands.

Comment: Based on your edit, I would create a wrapper so you don't repeat the code.

Comment: How are you going to be passing in the arguments?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I made my second edit explaining how, I try using the click library. I wrote an implementation. I still have to make the decorator you told me about.

Comment: Does `echo "'original content'"` change the output?

Comment: Yes, it eats the first apostrophe: `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (o r i g i n a l   c o n t e n t ' 
)`

Comment: what about `echo "'original content'" | xargs  add_name_and_surname`?

Comment: `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (r i g i n a l   c o n t e n t)`. Anyway that would make for a click-related question! Do you think this approach is workable, is it farfetched, are there better solutions to use functions as piping commands?